# Does an external hard drive draw more current writing or deleting files?

Tags: external-hard-drive, power, time-machine

I have an external hard drive that is powered off of the usb connection to my Raspberry Pi. I use it for Time Machine back ups so it is almost always writing data to the external hard drive. However, the other day the hard drive was full and Time Machine began removing old back ups to free up some space. This crashed the hard drive and damaged the file system. I have tried it a few times since and whenever Time Machine tries to delete old back ups the system crashes. My assumption is that it's because the RPi can't source much current so if the current draw during file deletion is higher than during writing, it may be just enough to cause the disk to crash.

Comment: Deleting files does involve writing to the disk, so the distinction you're trying to make is probably irrelevant.  Searching for files to delete, and then deleting.them seems like more disk activity than an ordinary backup. *"This crashed the hard drive"*  -- A HDD crash usually  means a mechanical failure, not a simple loss of power.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't. Every harddisk has an index. Deleting a file is nothing more than editing the index and remove the allocations for a file. (True these can span one ore more sectors) This is so much quicker than writing data (as data is usually more than 1 megabyte, and thus several dozen sectors), that its more likely that something with this index is corrupt.

But if it is a mechanical drive, the head has to move to the beginning of the harddrive where the index is. If it does this while also writing to the disk, that mechanical head will be moving quite a lot. This may actually increase power consumption, but it should be neglectable.

Comment: *"Deleting a file is nothing more than editing the index and remove the allocations for a file."* -- This is misleading, as if only a few bytes have to be written to the HDD.  Disk drives are block devices, you always have to read/write a complete physical block (aka sector).  If you want to change the value of one bit, then the entire sector has to be read, the bit changed, and then the entire sector written back.

Comment: @sawdust you're right. Still its significantly less than writing to a file, especially if the file is larger, say 1 megabyte or more.